# Specify supportedruntimeversion without a config file

Tags: .net

I have a Windows Form application with TargetPlatform x86 and TargetFrameworkVersion 4.0 set. When it is run on an x64 machine, it works fine but on an x86 machine it gives the following error on startup (both of the machines have .net framework version 4.0):

This application could not be started. Do you want to view more information about this issue?

Clicking on ‘Yes’ takes me to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2715633. (SHIM_NOVERSION_FOUND)

I added a config file to the project with ‘supportedruntimeversion’ as 4.0 and it started working.

Is there a reason the application automatically detects the runtime version for x64 machines, but needs a config file for x86 machines? Is there any other way to specify the runtime version (apart from the config file) ?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you check in your application properties EXACTLY which run-time version you address? "Normal" or "client profile"?

Comment: You are not actually targeting 4.0 in your EXE project.  Your target is 3.5 or less, the machine that complains does not have it installed.  A Windows 8.x machine probably.  Fix your target or simply get 3.5 installed on that machine.

Comment: @Hans I have tried enabling .net framework 3.5 on the machine. That did not work either. Why do you say the target is 3.5 or less? The csproj file has TargetFrameworkVersion set to 4.0.

Comment: @Adriano I checked and I address the "Normal" version. The target machine has the normal version too.